# Google Game Services - Signing certificate fingerprint (SHA1). Debug keystore is always invalid

Tags: android, certificate, google-play-services, sha1, android-keystore

I'm following a guide on https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/playservices_unity/index.html#0.

I've got stuck at Creating Android OAuth Client. For some reason my debug.keystore SHA1 is always invalid.

I've followed every step in guide several times. Tried different pc's.

1. Player properties in unity engine are filled properly
2. I'm using CMD line `keytool -list -v -keystore $DEBUG_KEYSTORE -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`  to get my debug.keystore.
3. My SHA1 code works in https://console.developers.google.com/apis/ but when it comes to google play console its always invalid.
4. I've tried to create different keys, recreate existing debug.keystore,
5. Looked for different posts, didn't find anything

Comment: I have been struggling with this one also since yesterday, and im feeling i have gone through all the available tutorials already. Maybe some problem with Play Console?

Comment: I've contacted Google Play Console support. I'm waiting for their answer. I will post if anything comes up :)

Comment: Good, I also found another post from a week ago, about this same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56603397/certificate-fingerprint-is-invalid

Comment: I've contacted Google Play Developer Support. Here is their answer : Please ensure the key is set to 2048 bit and is valid for at least 25 years. I've tried it, but sadly my debug.keystore is still not getting accepted, maybe there will be some luck on your side. $ keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000